# Android studio blank activity throws error

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I'm very much new in this android developing field. I just wanted to run the **hello world program** that is given by default in android studio as a startup under blank activity. I have done nothing with the code or any elements. But it throws **following errors**. What should I do? Please anyone help me.
It throws something like this:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that match the given name'android:TextAppearence.Materials.Widget.Button.Inverse'

and **more 2 errors** like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle file, update the following values under "android":

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
```

Also, ensure that you have Android M Libraries (v23) downloaded.  You can check this by going through the SDK Manager in the Android Studio toolbar.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Banes (Support librtary developer) says in Google Plus

https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/ekKcJwtCW9U

You have to put `compileSdkVersion` to 23 in your gradle